# Sqlalchemy: avoiding multiple inheritance and having abstract base class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiple-inheritance

So I have a bunch of tables using SQLAlchemy that are modelled as objects which inherit from the result to a call to `declarative_base()`.  Ie:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Table1(Base):
    # __tablename__ & such here

class Table2(Base):
     # __tablename__ & such here
```

Etc.  I then wanted to have some common functionality available to each of my DB table classes, [the easiest way to do this according to the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html#declarative-mixins) is to just do multiple inheritance:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class CommonRoutines(object):
    @classmethod
    def somecommonaction(cls):
        # body here

class Table1(CommonRoutines, Base):
    # __tablename__ & such here

class Table2(CommonRoutines, Base):
     # __tablename__ & such here
```

The thing I don't like about this is A) multiple inheritance in general is a bit icky (gets tricky resolving things like `super()` calls, etc), B) if I add a new table I have to remember to inherit from both `Base` and `CommonRoutines`, and C) really that "CommonRoutines" class "is-a" type of table in a sense.  Really what `CommonBase` is is an abstract base class which defines a set of fields & routines which are common to all tables.  Put another way: "its-a" abstract table.

So, what I'd like is this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class AbstractTable(Base):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta  # make into abstract base class

    # define common attributes for all tables here, like maybe:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def somecommonaction(cls):
        # body here

class Table1(AbstractTable):
    # __tablename__ & Table1 specific fields here

class Table2(AbstractTable):
     # __tablename__ & Table2 specific fields here
```

But this of course doesn't work, as I then have to A) define a `__tablename__` for `AbstractTable`, B) the ABC aspect of things causes all sorts of headaches, and C) have to indicate some sort of DB relationship between `AbstractTable` and each individual table.

So my question: is it possible to achieve this in a reasonable way?  Ideally I'd like to enforce:

- No multiple inheritance
- `CommonBase`/`AbstractTable` be abstract (ie cannot be instantiated)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is pretty straigh-forward, you just make `declarative_base()` to return a `Base` class which inherits from your `CommonBase` using `cls=` parameter. Also shown in [Augmenting The Base](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html?highlight=declarative_base#augmenting-the-base) docs. Your code might then look similar to below:

```
class CommonBase(object):
    @classmethod
    def somecommonaction(cls):
        # body here

Base = declarative_base(cls=CommonBase)

class Table1(Base):
    # __tablename__ & Table1 specific fields here

class Table2(Base):
     # __tablename__ & Table2 specific fields here
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but those "AbstractTable" inheritances should read "Base", correct? (ie `class Table1(Base):`)

Comment: Yup, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!  The only drawback to the approach is that now the `CommonBase` class's `__init__` does not get called (`declarative_base` produces a class which doesn't call `super` in its `__init__` so Python's cooperative multiple inheritance mechanisms don't work). Hmm....

Answer (score 58):

SQLAlchemy version 0.7.3 introduced the `__abstract__` directive which is used for abstract classes that should not be mapped to a database table, even though they are subclasses of *sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base*. So now you create a base class like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class CommonRoutines(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
```

Notice how `CommonRoutines` doesn't have a `__tablename__` attribute. Then create subclasses like this:

```
class Foo(CommonRoutines):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    name = Column(...)

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        # ...
```

This will map to the table `foo` and inherit the `id` attribute from `CommonRoutines`.

Source and more information: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#abstract

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. SqlAlchemy reports the lack of a `__tablename__` as an error when creating the abstract class

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: I recommend scrolling down to the confirmed answer but here is a working link to the declarative abstract link shared by Aston. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract

Answer (score 4):

You can use AbstractConcreteBase to make an absract base model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import AbstractConcreteBase


class AbstractTable(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def somecommonaction(cls):
        # body here
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have several models with common columns, then you can use `__abstract__` and `@declared_attr` to inherit shared table attributes. Example:

```py
Base = declarative_base()

class CommonRoutines(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    modified_at = Column(DateTime)
    
    @declared_attr
    def modified_by(self):
        # `user.id` is another table called `user` with an `id` field
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', name='fk_modified_by_user_id')) 


    def __init__(self):
        self.modified_by = None
        super().__init__()


class Foo(CommonRoutines):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    name = Column(...)
```

With this solution you will have a `Foo` table with the fields of `Foo` class (`name`) and the ones in `CommonRoutines` (`id`, `modified_at` and `modified_by`)